# How to organize Youtube play lists in Alphabetical order under the Save button?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, sorting

I've created many YouTube playlists and it's getting harder and harder to find the right playlist when I click on save as they are not sorted alphabetically.

Is there a way to sort the playlists alphabetically under the save button, and if not is there a better solution to organize YouTube videos?

Thanks

Comment: Same issue here, they seem to be listed by most recent video saved. A search field (akin to itch.io "add to collection" popup) would also do the job. Sometimes, you add many videos to the same playlist, so sorting by recent usage is still useful, and a button to switch sorting style would be the best.

But I see no solution in other threads:
https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/14099203/how-can-i-get-playlists-in-alphabetical-order-to-select-a-playlist-to-save-a-video-clip (2019)
https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/m9j7wd/when_saving_a_video_to_a_playlist_why_is_there_no/ (2021)

Answer (score 0):

On a PC, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Find) in a web browser to find the playlist.

1. In your browser, click "save to playlist"
2. Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up your browser's FIND dialog
3. Type in the name of the playlist
4. If the name of the playlist you're searching for is found multiple times, go to the last one, which will be the actual playlist.

This makes it a bit easier.

[image: snapshot showing find box and modal dialog]